# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while encoding in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read big files in Spark Scala and trying to perform join on then .
When I test with the small files it works very well but with bigger files I get some time below error .

I managed to pull out one of the files for which I was getting error .
The file size is 1 GB and while creating the partition at last this error is thrown where I split file name to get the column .

Right after this line

```
 val rdd = sc.textFile(mainFileURL)
      val header = rdd.filter(_.contains("uniqueFundamentalSet")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
      val schema = StructType(header.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
      println(schema)
      val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("uniqueFundamentalSet")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema)
```

This is the culprit line

```
 val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("uniqueFundamentalSet")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema)
```

Please suggest how can I handle this.

When I do rdd.count I get value .
But when I do data.count() I get the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 37
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, uniqueFundamentalSet), StringType), true) AS uniqueFundamentalSet#0
I
```

Here is my sample data set

```
uniqueFundamentalSet|^|PeriodId|^|SourceId|^|StatementTypeCode|^|StatementCurrencyId|^|FinancialStatementLineItem.lineItemId|^|FinancialAsReportedLineItemName|^|FinancialAsReportedLineItemName.languageId|^|FinancialStatementLineItemValue|^|AdjustedForCorporateActionValue|^|ReportedCurrencyId|^|IsAsReportedCurrencySetManually|^|Unit|^|IsTotal|^|StatementSectionCode|^|DimentionalLineItemId|^|IsDerived|^|EstimateMethodCode|^|EstimateMethodNote|^|EstimateMethodNote.languageId|^|FinancialLineItemSource|^|IsCombinedItem|^|IsExcludedFromStandardization|^|DocByteOffset|^|DocByteLength|^|BookMark|^|ItemDisplayedNegativeFlag|^|ItemScalingFactor|^|ItemDisplayedValue|^|ReportedValue|^|EditedDescription|^|EditedDescription.languageId|^|ReportedDescription|^|ReportedDescription.languageId|^|AsReportedInstanceSequence|^|PhysicalMeasureId|^|FinancialStatementLineItemSequence|^|SystemDerivedTypeCode|^|AsReportedExchangeRate|^|AsReportedExchangeRateSourceCurrencyId|^|ThirdPartySourceCode|^|FinancialStatementLineItemValueUpperRange|^|FinancialStatementLineItemLocalLanguageLabel|^|FinancialStatementLineItemLocalLanguageLabel.languageId|^|IsFinal|^|FinancialStatementLineItem.lineItemInstanceKey|^|StatementSectionIsCredit|^|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|^|ParentLineItemId|^|EstimateMethodId|^|StatementSectionId|^|SystemDerivedTypeCodeId|^|UnitEnumerationId|^|FiscalYear|^|IsAnnual|^|PeriodPermId|^|PeriodPermId.objectTypeId|^|PeriodPermId.objectType|^|AuditID|^|AsReportedItemId|^|ExpressionInstanceId|^|ExpressionText|^|FFAction|!|
192730239205|^|235|^|1|^|FTN|^|500186|^|221|^|Average Age of Employees|^|505074|^|30.00000|^||^||^|False|^|1.00000|^|False|^|EMP|^||^|False|^|ARV|^||^|505074|^||^|False|^|False|^||^||^||^||^|0|^||^||^||^|505074|^||^|505074|^||^||^|122880|^|NA|^||^||^|TK |^||^||^|505126|^|True|^|1235002211206722736|^|True|^||^||^|3019656|^|3013652|^|3019679|^|1010066|^|1976|^|True|^||^|1000220295|^||^||^||^||^||^|I|!|
```

Comment: please post the exact line of code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan it Is in the `dataMain.join(latestForEachKey`

Comment: you must have a mistake as there is no code to give you arrayindexoutofbound exception on that line

Comment: The full stacktrace of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` would be helpful, if you have it.

Comment: you should post the codes for the creation of `dataMain` and `latestForEachKey` I think thats where the exception is thrown

Comment: @RameshMaharjan updated sir

Comment: please post how `df2resultTimestamp` and `df1resultFinalwithTimestamp` are created ?

Comment: focus on these lines as I suspect them `val getPartition = sqlContext.udf.register("getPartition", (filePath: String) => filePath.split("\\.")(3))
    val getYearAndStatementTypeCodePartition = sqlContext.udf.register("getPartition", (filePath: String) => filePath.split("\\.")(4))
    val get_partition_Year = sqlContext.udf.register("get_partition_Year", (df1resultFinal: String) => df1resultFinal.split("-")(0))
    val get_partition_Statement = sqlContext.udf.register("get_partition_Year", (df1resultFinal: String) => df1resultFinal.split("-")(1))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167197/discussion-between-atharv-thakur-and-ramesh-maharjan).

Comment: nope thats not possible

Comment: Nope thats not the part where the error exists. Thats the part where you did an action of writing data to ouput path. In spark all the transformation happens when an action is performed. So if you do some action before that part it may seem that the error occured before that part. keep debugging.

Comment: @TzachZohar Sir I have updated the question where I was getting error ..I am getting this while spark creates partition for the bigger file only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**filter out the rows which doesn't match**

One of the easiest way is to *filter out all the rows which doesn't match the length of schema before applying the schema to form a dataframe* as

```
val requiredNumberOfFields = schema.fieldNames.length   //added to take the number of columns required
val data = sqlContext
  .createDataFrame(
    rdd
      .filter(!_.contains("uniqueFundamentalSet"))
      .map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|"))
      .filter(_.length == requiredNumberOfFields)    //added to filter in only the rows which has the same number of fields required in schema
      .map(x => Row.fromSeq(x.toSeq))
    , schema)
```

**add dummy strings or filter out extra strings**

You can write a function to check for the length. If the length of data is less than the schema then you can add dummy strings. If the length of the data is more you can drop the extra data

```
val requiredNumberOfFields = schema.fieldNames.length
def appendDummyData(row: Array[String], len: Int) = row.length == len match {
  case true => row
  case false => if(len > row.length) {
    val add = (for(loop <- 1 to len - row.length) yield "dummy").toArray
    row ++ add
  } else row.take(len)
}
val data = sqlContext
  .createDataFrame(
    rdd
      .filter(!_.contains("uniqueFundamentalSet"))
      .map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|"))
      .map(x => Row.fromSeq(appendDummyData(x, requiredNumberOfFields).toSeq))   //calling the custom function for checking the length
    , schema)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: so whats the problem ..The issue is delimiter ? Can we get any how which lines are creating problem ...I was looking at you same kind of solution that you have posted..This solution is working

Comment: You can filter in the mismatching rows in a seprate variable and print them and see or you can store them for further analysis. I am going to give you another solution of adding dummy strings. so that when the dataframe is created you can analyze them

Comment: When I try to find the mismatch row with this ` .filter(_.length == requiredNumberOfFields)` then also I am getting error ...Not able to find exactly which line has mismatch

Comment: what error are you getting? and did you try the other method I just updated.

Comment: Yes that Is also working ...But not able to identify the exact line

Comment: do `val notmatching = rdd.filter(!_.contains("uniqueFundamentalSet")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).filter(_.length != requiredNumberOfFields)` and print the `notmatching` to see the errored lines or save it in a file using `saveAsTextFile` then you analyze the lines for the cause of errors